# meaning of community change organizations

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

what is the mean of this phrase in the following sentence ?

> refurbished computers are either granted to schools, churches, non-profit or **community change organizations**, given to volunteers, or sold in Free Geek's thrift store.

Comment: It's not a set phrase or idiom. It is a sequence of words with their usual meaning - see their respective definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"community change organization" should be interpreted as "*organization* whose goal is to promote *change* in the *community*". In other words, "community" qualifies "change", indicating what kind of change is involved, and then "community change" qualifies "organization", indicating the purpose of the organization. English allows you to string qualifiers together like this as much as you want, although if you do it too much the phrase can become very confusing.

Comment: Please see my comment at OP.

Comment: That's true, but understanding it still requires understanding how the words are grouped and what modifies what.

Answer (score 0):

Former President Obama worked for a community change organization years ago in Chicago. The purpose of such usually nonprofit organizations is to bring about positive changes in communities which need them. Typical projects of such organizations include voter registration, free- or low cost legal help, establishment of food banks for poorer residents and programs for seniors and handicapped citizens, lobbying at the local level for political changes which will benefit communities.

Such organizations would likely welcome the donation of refurbished computers, since money for daily operations is often tight, and maintaining an office with employees is expensive. Even volunteers for the organization need tools, such as computers, to do their valuable work.